# TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, jquery, веб-программирование, fileupload

Есть скрипт с выбором файла/изображения. Я спрятал стандартный `input`. Но при выборе файла по клике на надпись "Фото" получаю ошибку *TypeError: Argument 1 is not valid for any of the 1-argument overloads of URL.createObjectURL.*

https://playcode.io/312105?tabs=console&index.html&output

```js
function addPostImage(event, element) {
  var files = element.files,
      file_list = [];
  file_list.push(files[0]);
  var file = file_list.pop();
  $('#id_post_image').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(file));
  $('#id_post_media').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/post/user/17/user/22/add/" id="id_new_post" name="new_post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="submit_post">
    <div class="media_preview_wrap" style="display: none;" id="id_post_media">
      <div class="media_preview">
        <div class="preview">
          <img src="" width="30" height="30" id="id_post_image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="file" name="form-0-image" id="id_form-0-image" onclick="addPostImage(event, this)" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_media flaticon-paper-clip-outline">
    <span class="add_media_list">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('#id_form-0-image').click()">
        <span class="flaticon-art"></span>
        <span>Фото</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: А если не прятать стандартный инпут, и нажать на стандартную кнопочку - ваш код работает?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

заменить на

```
window.URL.srcObject = file
```

[Причина](https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5618491470118912) простая... И аналогично у остальных можно [найти](https://www.fxsitecompat.com/en-CA/docs/2017/url-createobjecturl-stream-has-been-deprecated/)

Comment: А вы смотрели приведенный в вопросе код? Там ошибочка совсем не в этом...

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko ну вообще в этом, видимо. Только почему-то превью загруженного изображения некорректно работает в блоке `#id_post_media`.(

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko, Ошибка в этом, вы бы разобрались прежде чем минусовать...

Comment: @id_post_media есть подозрения что у вас файлы не записываются попросту

Comment: Ошибка в том, что переменная `file === undefined`, потому что событие стоит `click`, во время `click` файл еще не выбран. Вот это в консоли выполните `window.URL.createObjectURL(undefined)`, получите ту же самую ошибку.

Comment: Cпасибо. Нужно было `onchange` выбрать. Тогда, кстати, и не ругается на `window.URL.createObjectURL(file)`

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko оформите свой комментарий, как ответ. Может, кому-то ещё пригодится.

Comment: @pythoner Я предпочитаю, что бы вы сами оформили ответ, если поняли причину ошибки и поняли, как ее исправить! Это будет просто замечательно!

Comment: Как применяется функция не смотрел, тут мой косяк, согласен.. На днях для себя библиотеку небольшую писал и таким образом исправил этуже ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Помог комментарий @StepanKasyanenko

Чтобы исправить данную ошибку, достаточно прислушаться к ответу @InDevX

```
window.URL.createObjectURL(file)
```

заменить на

```
window.URL.srcObject = file
```

Но если нужно, чтобы загруженное изображение отображалось в `id_post_media`, нужно событие `onclick` сменить на `onchange` в `<input type="file" name="form-0-image" id="id_form-0-image" onclick="addPostImage(event, this)" />`. И в этом случае ответ @InDevX применять нужно. Вот так забавно устроен `jquery`

```js
function addPostImage(event, element) {
  var files = element.files,
      file_list = [];
  file_list.push(files[0]);
  var file = file_list.pop();
  $('#id_post_image').attr('src', window.URL.srcObject = file);
  $('#id_post_media').fadeIn('fast');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="/post/user/17/user/22/add/" id="id_new_post" name="new_post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <div class="submit_post">
    <div class="media_preview_wrap" style="display: none;" id="id_post_media">
      <div class="media_preview">
        <div class="preview">
          <img src="" width="30" height="30" id="id_post_image">
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="file" name="form-0-image" id="id_form-0-image" onchange="addPostImage(event, this)" style="display: none" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="add_media flaticon-paper-clip-outline">
    <span class="add_media_list">
      <a href="#" onclick="document.querySelector('#id_form-0-image').click()">
        <span class="flaticon-art"></span>
        <span>Фото</span>
      </a>
    </span>
  </div>
</form>
```